# Best Way to Parse this XML File

Tags: android, xml, musicbrainz

I am trying to parse the XML file that I retreive from the following URL using an Http Request in Android:

http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=kick%20AND%20artist:inxs

What would be the best way to parse it? I need to find the artist name, the album title and release id. I have been trying to use the method specified here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

But it it turning out to be really ineffecient. Any suggestion for a library or an easier method I can use to retrieve the required information?

My code so far is as follows:

```
public List parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List entries = new ArrayList();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "metadata");
    Log.i("XMLParser", "metadata");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("recording-list")) {
            Log.i("XMLParser", "recording-list");
            entries.add(readRecordingList(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }  
    return entries;
}

private Recording readRecordingList(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "recording-list");
    Recording recording=new Recording(null,null,null,null);

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("recording")) {
            Log.i("XMLParser", "recording");
            recording = readRecording(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return recording;
}

private Recording readRecording(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "recording");
    Recording recording=new Recording(null,null,null,null);
    String albumTitle=null;
    String artistName=null;

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        Log.i("XMLParserNodeName", name);
        if (name.equals("title")) {
            Log.i("XMLParser", "title");
            albumTitle=readTitle(parser);
            Log.i("XMLParser", albumTitle);
            //recording = readRecording(parser);
        }else if(name.equals("name")){ 
            Log.i("XMLParser", "name");
            name=readArtistName(parser);
            Log.i("XMLParser", name);
        }else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return recording;
}


private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            depth--;
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            depth++;
            break;
        }
    }
 }

private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}

private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
    String title = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
    return title;
}

private String readArtistName(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "name");
    String name = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "name");
    return name;
}

public static class Recording {


        public final String recordingTitle;
        public final String releaseTitle;
        public final String releaseID;
        public final String artistName;

        public Recording(String recordingTitle, String releaseTitle,
                String releaseID, String artistName) {
            this.recordingTitle = recordingTitle;
            this.releaseTitle = releaseTitle;
            this.releaseID = releaseID;
            this.artistName = artistName;
        }    
}
```

}

Basically this is an adaptation from the XML Pull Parser Tutorial in Android but I want to avoid writing so much code each node and the xml file has a lot of them. I think I would prefer XML Pull Parser over DOM so that I don't consume a lot of memory.

Comment: Either SAX or DOM, both of which are [well-supported in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/) are my go-to XML parsing mechanisms. Never used pull parsing, but I'm assured it is equivalent.

Comment: Show us your code and we might be able to help make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation of the MusicBrainz Web Service](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2#Libraries_to_use_the_Web_Service) mentions a java library that can be used: [musicbrainzws2-java](http://code.google.com/p/musicbrainzws2-java/).

I don't have experience with that particular library, but these libraries tend to provide an API to transparently request entities from MusicBrainz. Choosing the right end point and parsing is done by the library.

You are not the first one trying to use the MusicBrainz Web Service with Java ;-)

---

The [wiki of the library](http://code.google.com/p/musicbrainzws2-java/wiki/Usage_Search#Example) has some examples on how to use it to search.